# Click em item da listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick

Tenho o seguinte código, que mostra os itens em uma lista, na tela:

Activity:

```
public class InviteActivity extends ListActivity implements InviteView
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite);
        setListAdapter(new InvitePresenter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class InvitePresenter extends BaseAdapter {

    private InviteView inviteView;
    private List<UserCommunity> usersList = new ArrayList<UserCommunity>();

    public InvitePresenter(InviteView inviteView){
        this.inviteView = inviteView;
        RequestManager.Users(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                usersList =  new Gson().fromJson(result.get("data"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserCommunity>>() {}.getType());
                if (usersList != null) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return usersList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //recupera o estado da posição atual
        UserCommunity inviteUsers = usersList.get(position);

        //Cria uma instancia do layout .. na view
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)inviteView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_invite_listview,null);

        TextView txt_Nome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_invite);
        TextView txt_Email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_email_invite);
        TextView txt_Distancia = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_distancia_invite);

        txt_Nome.setText(inviteUsers.name);
        txt_Email.setText(inviteUsers.email);
        txt_Distancia.setText(Integer.toString(inviteUsers.distance));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de implementar um click, em um item da lista. Então será aberto uma nova activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando as informações do id do seu listview, e o resto do código da activity, mas aqui está um exemplo de como implementar o clique no listview, você o referencia no onCreate e então "seta" o onItemClickListener, ali dentro você faz o código pra trocar de atividade usando intents.

```
public class InviteActivity extends ListActivity implements InviteView {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite);
        setListAdapter(new InvitePresenter(this));

        ListView listview = (Listview) findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //Seu codigo aqui
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, NovaAtividade.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext(){
        return this;
    }
```

De novo, código não é copia e cola, porque depende de umas variáveis suas, mas tem uma boa base pra você começar.

Link pra documentação do OnItemClickListener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Link pra documentação sobre Intents, pra você entender melhor como trocar de atividade: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: o codigo da activity é só este mesmo, o listview é somente o xml, posso colocá-lo

Comment: Monto tudo no presenter, q herda do adapter, e retorno para a view(Activity)

Comment: @HenriqueMendes mas o listener de clique no item fica na activity ou no fragment que for o "pai" do ListView. Ficou alguma dúvida?

Comment: Nao, compreendi sim. Muito Obrigado!